# How to display every sub page of the parent of the current page in aem?

Tags: aem, sightly

I want to display names of every child pages of the parent of the current page except the current page in the component in aem. But my output is coming including the current page name.

```
 <section id="touractivities">
            <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                         <ul class="row buttontab">
                           <li class="col-md col-sm-4 col-6"  data-sly-repeat="${CurrentPage.parent.listChildren}">
                              <div class="btnbggradient">
                                        <a href="${item.path}.html" class="shadow">
                                        <i class="icon-${item.name}"></i>
                                        <h5 >${item.title}</h5>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                              </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div></section>
```

**my aem structure:**

[image: my aem structure]

**required output:**

[image: required output]

**output im getting:**

[image: output im getting]

The code is correct except that the bird watching li should not come while i am in bird watching page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<section id="touractivities">
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <ul class="row buttontab" data-sly-list="${CurrentPage.parent.listChildren}">

                                   <li class="col-md col-sm-4 col-6" data-sly-test="${item.path != currentPage.path}" >
                                        <div class="btnbggradient">
                                            <a href="${item.path}.html" class="shadow">
                                            <i class="icon-${item.name}"></i>
                                            <h5 >${item.title}</h5>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div></section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch from `data-sly-repeat` to `data-sly-list` (so you can move it to the `ul` element). You can then use `data-sly-test` on the `li` element and check each item path against the current resource/page path:

```
<li data-sly-test=“${item.path != resource.path}” ...
```